# Reaching a desired orientation under constant angular momentum

Tags: rotational-dynamics

For a rigid body with a given inertia tensor, and a target orientation and time, how can I determine a constant angular momentum that will move the body to the target orientation?

I see this could be solved numerically as a boundary value problem using the equations of motion for a rigid body. But when the inertia tensor is symmetric, there's a simple solution via determining a constant angular velocity from the logarithm of the target orientation. Is there a similar simple solution for asymmetric inertia tensors, or does the asymmetry really make this problem much more difficult to solve?

Comment: Do you have an explicit example that would help put this into context? (Just make sure the question doesn't read as a homework problem)

Comment: An explicit example: Suppose I want to rotate a rigid body 1 radian about the x-axis in 1 second. I'm free to specify the initial angular velocity/momentum but otherwise no torque can act on the body (so the angular momentum is constant).

Comment: For a symmetric moment of inertia tensor, this is simple: the angular velocity is 1 radian per second about the x-axis. But for an asymmetric inertia tensor, I don't see a simple solution.

Comment: It might be better to say you have a target rotation through some angle around some axis then.